# Passing array as argument BUT individually

Tags: java, arguments

I want to have an abstract function such as

```
init(int... conditions);
```

So that inherited classes can have variety of init conditions; may some classes require less number of arugments and may others will take more than the others.

However I wish to rather pass them individually like following

```
init(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]... arr[size-1]);
```

than

```
init(arr);
```

Is such approach possible? If not, then should I be better of just passing an array?

---

Sorry for the confusion that I seem to create.

I have an array of size n that varies.
I cannot hard code passing the argument because the number of arguments is dependable.
I do not want to go for function overload for different versions of init method because that will create about dozen of different versions of init method.

Comment: Why do you want to pass them individually?  Varargs were implemented to make it so we *didn't* have to do that.

Comment: It's not possible to do for an arbitrary size - only a small finite set of call variations can be written but `n` is [relatively] unbounded. Create the appropriate array (e.g. add or remove elements) and va-args (`...`) will automatically accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to overload the method. Just use the so called `variable arguments`. The are available in Java since version 1.5. For example:

```
public void init(int... conditions) { ... }
```

You can use the method in two ways:

1. Pass the array itself. Like this:

   init(array);
2. Pass each of the array elements. Like this:

   init(array[0], array[1], ... array[n]);

Note that if you want to have other arguments for this method, they should be placed in the method signature only before the variable arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the variable arguments method parameter.  In fact it has the same method signature as what you posted above.

```
public void init(int... conditions){}
```

This makes conditions an int[], which you can iterate over to get your init conditions.